# Where can I ask questions related to Cisco routers and GNS?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am preparing for CCNP and I have many questions regarding GNS3, IOS and Cisco routers. I am confused where can I ask those questions. CISCO is a big community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are a sysadmin (I assume you are as you are preparing for an exam) then [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) is the place to ask.